# How do you cancel navigation in MvvmCross 6.x?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm converting an MVVMCross 4.x app to MvvmCross 6.x.

Previously if I wanted to intercept the showing of a view model and cancel it then I would subclass the MvxViewPresenter and override the `Task<bool> Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)` method. I'm struggling to find the equivalant in MvvmCross 6.0

I've tried hooking in to the `Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>().BeforeNavigate` event but this gets called after the `Prepare()` and `Initialize()` view model methods.

How do I intercept the call before the `ViewModel.Initialize()` method is called and cancel the navigation?

Comment: Why is it that you cannot intercept the Show method? It is still there.

Comment: I can intercept it, but it's called after the ViewModel.Initialize(). Previously it was called before VIewModel.Init() (in fact I think it was called before the ViewModel constructor)

Comment: LoadViewModel will be called immediately when you call `NavigationService.Navigate` so it is really possible anymore: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Navigation/MvxNavigationService.cs#L434 this will trigger a lot of the lifecycle. Can you maybe describe a more specific use case, I don't understand why this would be useful.

Comment: There are a number of place in the app where an 'input form view' can be displayed. Depending on the users permissions (and other logic) I want to intercept the call and not display the input form and instead display a dialog box

Comment: Why don't you just that logic in the first ViewModel so it doesn't go to the next page without passing the check?

Comment: @Cheesebaron This will be very useful to prevent double tapping of a button throughout the whole app. Sometimes people tap buttons twice very quickly, causing double navigation. Being able to cancel earlier in the lifecycle allows very neat prevention of this problem without having to do ugly bool checks every time we call IMvxNavigationService.Navigate.

Comment: Debounce your command instead then?

Comment: @Cheesebaron might be a bit unrelated to the SO question at hand, but any hints/clues on how to do that?